# Trying to get user timeline from twitter using application-only authentication

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, twitter

I'm trying to get a simple app working from within Flash to see a users tweets.

I 'believe' I have correctly gotten the access token.

```
var bearerToken:String;
var consumerKey:String = <CONSUMER_KEY>;
var consumerSecret:String = <CONSUMER_SECRET>;

//encode key and secret according to twitter's website
var bearerTokenCredentials = Base64.encode(consumerKey + ':' + consumerSecret);

//setup my request variables, according to twitters dev info, use client_credentials for grant_type    
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.grant_type = 'client_credentials';
//according to twitter, the url to use for application-only authenticaton
var url:String = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token';

//setup a URLRequest object with the proper headers, according to twitter, need the Authorization header to be 'Basic <encoded key/secret>' and the proper Content-Type header
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + bearerTokenCredentials),
                          new URLRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8')];
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = requestVars;

//send the request to authenticate
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onBearerTokenRequest);
urlLoader.load(request);

function onBearerTokenRequest(e:Event):void
{
    trace('onRequestComplete');

    //this works and i get a token
    bearerToken = JSON.decode(e.currentTarget.data).access_token;

    //HERE IS WHERE I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHAT'S WRONG
    var url:String =     'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'
    var urlVariables = new URLVariables();
    urlVariables.screen_name = 'rivercitygraphx';
    urlVariables.count = 2;

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    request.method = "GET";
    request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearerToken)];
    request.data = urlVariables;

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onTimelineRequestComplete);
    urlLoader.load(request);
}

function onTimelineRequestComplete(e:Event):void
{
    trace('onTimelineRequestComplete');
}
```

I get the token back properly (well I assume so since I get a long string).

But when I try to make the request for the user timeline I get an ioError Error opening URL 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen%5Fname=kamcknig&count=2' which makes me think the URL is malformed, but according to everytihng I see, it seems correct.

Also, right now I'm just testing this within the Flash IDE.

Can anyone help??

I have since used the POSTMAN extension in Chrome and entered the url, and the Authorization header with the bearer token that I received and the request worked within POSTMAN!

So the only thing that i can think is it's the Flash IDE. Anyone have any ideas why that might be or if that might actually even be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK after all my research it looks like this is impossible.

I have found a library that uses a socket connection that can do what I want, but the filesize is far too large. The Socket class in AS3 is not a secure socket so I can't use it. And the SecureSocket class can't be used either since I am limited to Flash Player 10 and earlier.

So as far as I'm concerned, this is impossible.